# How to change a single file type without affecting other file extensions in Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, file-types

I am attempting to set custom icons for a variety of file types. Those that I work with most so they stand out when looking through a list of files.

In this instance I have created special icons for `AVI` files, `DTS`, `FLAC`, `MP3`, `Wav`  etc.

If I want to change the `AVI` file to display my custom icon  I normally use an application called "*FileTypesMan*" and this has worked well in the past.

Windows, now seems to 'bundle' extensions together so that if  I make a change to the `AVI` file type it affects a laundry list of other extensions.

I would like a way that I can remove these specific extensions even if I have to create my own file categories in the registry to accomplish this.

Does anyone know where these 'groupings'  are located?
What,  or where is telling windows that all these extensions are 'together'

Answer (score 1):

File types are managed in increasingly complex ways in the Registry. For example, on this PC, in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT *.avi* has it's own key, and the key *OpenWithProgids* shows it's associated with Windows Media Player, yet the *icon* is that of *MPC-HC*, which I've set as the default app for video/avi mime type.

To separate out one extension to have a different icon, associate that extension with a particular *application* using Windows Explorer.

- Right-click on a file with the desired extension (here, *.avi*).
- Select *Open with >*.
- Select *Choose another app*.
- Select "Always use this app to open .avi files*.
- Find and select the app with the desired icon. and click *OK*.

In the image below, note that only the *.avi* file icon changed, after I switched the default app from [MPC-HC](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases) to [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/).

[image: Changing AVI icon]

Though it *might* be feasible to set your own icon in the Registry, due to the levels of indirection and grouping there that you've mentioned, and due to risks of editing the Registry, I'd avoid trying to do that.